# where do we use proxy script manager

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax

where do we use proxy script manager

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's useful on master pages. You can put a ScriptManager on master with all common jscripts and if you need to add another script on a specific page you can do it via proxy on the Content page.